# Ajax load page content after post form

Tags: jquery

This is my html page:

```
<body>
    <div id="containt">
         <p>already have containt.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="other">
        <form id="test">
             <input id="sth" name="sth" value="123456"/>
             <div id="submit"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
<body>
```

and my php script:"abc.php"

```
$happy['verymuch'] = $_POST['sth'];
include('needtogetcontent.php');//and then use extract() to extract $verymuch in "needtogetcontent.php"
```

"needtogetcontent.php"

```
<a href="<?=$verymuch?>"><?=$verymuch?></a>
```

Now I need to make html page like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="containt">
         <p>already have containt.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="other">
         <a href="123456">123456</a>
    </div>
<body>
```

Thanks for any help:D!

**Update: I used**

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'abc.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#test').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            //data will return anything echo/printed to the page.
            //based on your example, it's whatever $happy is.
            $('#other').text(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: We're not here to do your job for you. Show whatever code you've written to attempt this, and we'll try to help fix it. But until then, this is just "gimme the codez"

Comment: Sorry if my question make someone misunderstand. My English's not good so I'm apologize about that!
The reason for not posting my real code is to make every thing clearly. Please forgive me if I make something crazy man!:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#test').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'abc.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'sth='+$('#sth').val(),
        success: function(data){
            //data will return anything echo/printed to the page.
            //based on your example, it's whatever $happy is.
            $('#other').text(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I don't see a submit button, so I'm not sure if this process will actually work. If `<div id="submit">` is the element you click to submit the form, then we change ->

```
$('#test').submit(function(){
```

**To**

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
```

Comment: If you have multiple inputs, you use `$('#test').serialize()`;, if you have inputs with a name like `name="sth" value="123456"` and `name="ppi" value="7890"`, when you use `serialize()` it will be sent to the server like -> `sth=123456&ppi=7890`, we declared a type of `POST` in our ajax call, so you can retrieve it like -> `$_POST['sth']` and `$_POST['ppi']`.

Comment: If you don't want to use the serialize method, you can send it as a string like `"sth="+$('#sth').val()+"&ppi="+$('#ppi').val()`, which still produces a string like `sth=123456&ppi=7890`, which can still be parsed like `$_POST['sth'] and $_POST['ppi']` in your php file.

Comment: That mean I can use `data:$('#test').serialize()` and replace  `$('#other').text(data)` with ` $('#other').text(data)`,can't I? Thanks so much man!:D

Answer (score 0):

**Do the following:**

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="containt">
         <p>already have containt.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="other">
        <form id="test">
             <input id="sth" name="sth" value="123456"/>
             <div id="submit">Submit</div>
        </form>
    </div>
<body>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        //get sth value
        var sth = $('#sth').val();
        //make ajax call to 'abc.php' passing 'sth' parameter
        $.post('abc.php', { sth:sth }, function(data) {
            //if $_POST['sth'] at PHP side is not null
            if (data != null) {
                //show the data (in this case: $happy) in the div with id 'other' using '.html()' method
                $('#other').html(data);
            }
        });
    });

});​
```

Comment: like this: ´$.post('abc.php', { sth:sth, other:other }...´